# undefined method `stringify_keys!' ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have this code:

```
def addcar
  @car = Car.new(params[:car])
  render :action => 'list'
end

<% @allcars.each do |cell| %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to cell.to_s, :controller => 'car', :action => 'addcar', :car => cell.to_s %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

It's giving me this error:

> undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "Honda":String

I don't understand what is wrong with `:car`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

in the `addcar` method, you try to create a new object (`create`
method) while transfering just a string to it (`params[:car]` which apparently is set to "Honda").

`create` expects to get an attributes hash and to stringify it's keys for
the column names.

If you have a column named name in your cars table then try this:

```
@car = Car.new(:name => params[:car])
```

Comment: unfortunately that just gives me:
undefined local variable or method `carName' for #<CarsController:0x137cc67>