# undefined method `stringify_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, paperclip

When I try to upload image using Paperclip gem I got this error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000025387f0>)

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :image


end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :menu_item
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => {
            :large => "640x480",
            :medium => "300x300", 
            :thumb => "100x100" 
           }
end
```

Comment: Not much to go on... perhaps some details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined method \`stringify\_keys!' ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 74):

I've seen this error happen before, usually when people attempt to call `update_attributes` like this:

```
update_attributes(params[:image])
```

The call should actually be this:

```
update_attributes(:image => params[:image])
```

A bit of a shot in the dark, but if that's it I'm sure we'll all be impressed.

Comment: This did the trick for me as well, except I was using build() instead of update_attributes(). Thanks :)

Comment: @RyanBigg can you elaborate on the problem?I am having a similar issue with uploading a zip file which I create through Submission.uploaded_file = params[:submission]. Stringify Keys only happens when I have the CanCan gem turned on though.

Comment: Could the OP mark this as the correct answer? This fixed my issue as well.

Comment: @Hamdan: OMG YES!!!1one. Paperclip expects all the attributes for the image to be sent through as an 'image' attribute. What the OP was originally doing was not that.

Comment: Thats not what im asking. I actually cant understand how (:image => params[:image]) is different from (params[:image]) since what is inside params[:image] is actually the image object that the :image use to inherit its status of 'image object'. Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for a while in rails 3.2.2 I managed to solve this in this manner

> (image = Image.new(image: params[:image])).save
>
> update_attributes(image: image)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, and to clarify things a bit, update_attributes is different from update_attribute.

The following should work:

```
update_attributes(:image => params[:image])
```

or

```
update_attribute(:image, params[:image])
```

There you go!  There are other issues with update_attributes related to attr_accesible, but either works.