# ruby on rails self referential many to many through, how to add a related record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a simple merch association between two Products. I've followed a few tutorials and think I have it right, but it keep throwing an error whenever I try to add an associated item directly. I'm new to ROR, could someone help me understand what I've done wrong here?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :assoc_product,:product_id, :merch_associations, :aux_description,    :buyable, :long_description, :thumb_url, :full_url, :name, :on_special, :part_number,  :release_date, :short_description, :withdraw_date, :occasion
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :merch_associations
  has_many :assoc_products, :through => :merch_associations



searchable do
text :aux_description, :long_description, :name, :on_special, :part_number, :short_description
text :categories do 
  categories.map { |category| category.name }
end

        text :occasion

        string :categories, :multiple => true do
        categories.map {|category| category.name }
    end
    string :occasion
    time :release_date

  end
end

class MerchAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :assoc_product, :product_id  
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :assoc_product, :class_name => "Product"
end
```

Then in rails console:

```
Product.find(1).assoc_products.create(Product.last, :association_type => 'up_sell')
Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Product:0x007fc20d1ffd70>....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add object to relation by create, `create` method is for creating new objects with provided attributes. Read here: [undefined method `stringify_keys!' ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails)

Use `Product.find(1).assoc_product << Product.last` instead.

What is `association_type` param in your example? I guess you want to add related object with attributes for `MerchAssocation`? If so write:

```
Product.find(1).merch_associations.create(:assoc_product=>Product.last,:association_type => 'up_sell')
```

Comment: Thanks ok I tried that, and got the next error which was ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: association_type - association_type is a string value in the has many through: table.

Comment: class CreateMerchAssociations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :merch_associations do |t|
      t.integer :assoc_product_id
      t.integer :product_id
      t.string :association_type
      t.timestamps
    end
    
    add_index :merch_associations, :product_id
    add_index :merch_associations, :assoc_product_id
  end
end

Comment: add `association_type` to accessible attributes: `attr_accessible :assoc_product, :product_id, :association_type`

Comment: I think I tried that already:  class MerchAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :assoc_product, :product_id, :association_type

Comment: actually never mind I got it. I didn't notice you had a difference in the create command.  I was running this:  Product.find(1).assoc_products.create(:assoc_product => Product.last, :association_type => 'up_sell')   --- Notice the reference to assoc_products. It's a very different language to java, still trying to get around the nuances....thanks for the help