# when to use attributes hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this SO answer [undefined method `stringify_keys!' ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails), the OP tried to create a new car object with a  'Honda' string to the

```
 @car = Car.new(params[:car])
```

and got a stringify keys error. The person who answered said that he had to specify the column from the table (in this case the 'name' column) when creating the object ,

```
create expects to get an attributes hash and to stringify it's keys for the column names.

If you have a column named name in your cars table then try this:

@car = Car.new(:name => params[:car])
```

However, I'm watching a RailsCast where Rbates creates an entry table with 'name' string and a column 'winner' as a boolean. In his controller (which he's set to respond with json), he does not use an attributes hash. His create action

```
   def create
     respond_with Entry.create(params[:entry])
   end
```

Why didn't Rbates have to use an attributes hash, and, if he could have, what would that attributes hash look like? Something like this? Do you have to name every column, in ryans case :name and :winner?

```
   def create
     respond_with Entry.create(:name => params[:entry][:name], :winner => params[:entry]     [:winner]
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous question, params[:car] was a string. Rails's `new` and `create` methods both expect hashes, which is why the code was altered to pass in `:name => params[:car]`

If you use Rails's form_for to construct your forms, params[:model_name] will have a hash which keys matching model attributes. In that case, no custom work is necessary, and simply initializing the model with params[:model_name] works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what `params[:car]` contains. In the Railscast example, `params[:car]` is a Hash containing two entries (`name` and `winner`). In the other SO question it looks like `params[:car]` was a String containing the name of a car.

Car.new will always expect a Hash. If you want to pass a single value you need to turn it into a Hash with a key that tells Car.new what value you're passing.