# Undefined method `stringify_keys' for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error: `undefined method 'stringify_keys' for "3":String` after trying to edit my user resources. It seems the error is `@user.update_attributes`, but I don't understand why `params[:id]` won't work.

This is where it indicates the problem code is

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:id])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

This is my update form

```
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">


    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% end %>


      <%= f.label :username %>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails?rq=1

Comment: Tried that change but it didn't work unfortunately--

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug...

This line

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:id])
```

should be sending the user object

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user]) # note sending agency as hash not the id
```

Although you might want to familiarize yourself with Strong Params if you're using Rails 4.