# Rails - import CSV entry as array in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

I'm using a Ruby on Rails rake task to import a .csv file into my PostgreSQL database. My code, for reference, is below:

```
require 'csv'    

namespace :db do
    desc "Populate database"
    task populate_database: :environment do

        CSV.foreach("db.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
            Sale.create!(row.to_hash)
        end

    end
end
```

In the .csv file, I have an entry in the format "cat; dog; foo; bar". Right now, this entry is being imported into PostgreSQL as "text" (i.e. the data type). However, I'd like for the text to be split at "; " and the results of the split to be stored in PostgreSQL as a text ***array***.

How do I go about doing this?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

My data looks something like this:

```
      column 1          | column 2    | column 3
row 1 John              | Jack; Carol | Seth; Annie; Doug
row 2 Jim; Cassie; Jane | Anne        | Laura; Bob
```

Right now, when I run my rake task, "John" goes into PostgreSQL as text. "Laura; Bob" also goes into PostgreSQL as text. However, I'd like for "Laura; Bob" (and, similarly, "Jack; Carol", "Seth; Annie; Doug", and "Jim; Cassie; Jane") to go into PostgreSQL as a text **array**. One such array would look like [Jack, Carol].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
csv_file = open("363Live data v0.csv")
CSV.parse(csv_file.read, {:headers => true}).each do |row|
  # row is an array
  puts row.inspect
  Sale.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

**EDIT AFTER CLARIFICATION:**

Assumption - your multiple values are always separated by `;`
You may need to check for each cell if it has a `;` and then convert into array

```
# row => {"col1" => "John", "col2" => "Seth; Annie; Doug"}

CSV.foreach("363Live data v0.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
    row.to_hash.map do |key, value|
        row[key] = value.split(';').map {|v| v.strip} unless value.index(';').nil?
    end
    Sale.create!(row)
end

# row => {"col1"=>"John", "col2"=>["Seth", "Annie", "Doug"]}
```

Comment: Hi Nanda-- Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to turn an entry (such as "cat; dog; car") into an array. I don't actually want the entire row of data to be an array.

Comment: In that case, you can use `a="cat;dog;car"; a.split(";")` this returns an array

Comment: "cat; dog; car" and "foo; bar; are example entries in the .csv file, though.

Comment: that's alright. supposing you have `row` as a text and you want to split it by `;` use `row.split(";")`

Comment: Do you think you can look at my clarification? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your update! When I run this code, I get an `undefined method 'stringify_keys!'` error. Indeed, when I put a `puts row.class` (in place of where `Sale.create!(row)` is currently - that line is the [cause of the error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails)), it shows that `row` is still a `CSV::Row` object. This indicates to me that `row.to_hash` didn't do anything!

Comment: So, I modified your solution to say `row = row.to_hash.map do ...`. Because of that, `row` turns into an array. But that's also a problem, because I'm now having trouble converting the array to a hash (because the .create! method requires a hash).

Comment: Basically, what I'm saying is that when I use the `a.split("; ")` function, `row` turns into an array. If we can get `row` back to `CSV::Row` or `Hash`, then we're golden. That's what I'm trying to do right now, though with no success yet.