# Accessing PostgreSQL database in Ruby on Rails rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I'm populating my PostgreSQL using a Ruby on Rails rake task. I'd like to use a PostgreSQL array function (specifically, [text_to_array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html)) on every cell in my data table. How do I do so? Can I do so within the rake task?

See related: [Rails - import CSV entry as array in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22651755/398670)

Comment: Didn't you just ask this earlier? What's different? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22651755/398670

Comment: That other question involved using Ruby in the rake task. It didn't ask about using PostgreSQL code in a rake task.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. What do you intend to *do* with the output of `text_to_array`? Are you trying to change a column data type?

Comment: I'd like to put the output (a text array) into my PostgreSQL database so that I can query elements of that array. For example, if I start with "Subway; McDonald's", I'd like to change the entry to ["Subway", "McDonald's"] so that I can look up all instances of "Subway" in the corresponding column. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, so you *do* want to change the column data type - presumably from `text` to `text[]`. For that, you should use a Rails migration, using the `change_column` migration and a `USING` expression that uses `text_to_array`. Hopefully that gives you some idea where to start looking; I don't have time to write a full answer right now.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it - I'll look around.