# Undefined method `stringify_keys' for "4":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok this seems a very common problem, but looking online I can't seem to find a solution for my example.

When trying to update an object(product) using the below code I get the **undefined method `stringify_keys' for "4":String** NoMethod error page thrown back by Rails.

Here is the code to see if you can point out what I'm doing wrong:

**Product Controller**

```
  def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  if @product.update(params[:id])
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**The edit form View:**

```
<%= form_for(@product.id) do |f| %>

  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :descriptio %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm hoping I can get this to work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined method \`stringify\_keys!' ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: This line `if @product.update(params[:id])` is wrong.It should be `if @product.update(params[:product])`

Comment: `@product.update_attributes(params[:product])`

Comment: @Pavan unsure whether you'd like to place that as an answer so I can give you the credit for your help. Great answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This fragment is incorrect.

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  if @product.update(params[:id])
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

`update` expects an `Hash` of attributes, you are passing a `Fixnum` ID. It should be

```
@product.update(params[:product])
```

Ideally, you should also filter the input, as requested by the *strong parameters* feature.

```
@product.update(product_params)

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(...)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong.  Simone mentioned one in his answer.

If it is indeed as you posted, your edit form is incorrect.

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>   <-- no .id
```

The form is for an instance of the product model, not a FixNum.

The  <% end %> right after your form-for closes that form.

The label for description won't match with the text-field.

Perhaps you intend:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```